# In my avd emulator internet works but not in application

Tags: android, emulation, android-virtual-device

I have made an application in android studio, before this I have used nox player to run my application. But now I have installed windows on my laptop, and installed android studio and now I have installed an avd from android studio.
Before this, my application works fine, but now when I run the app with android avd, the application cant connect to server and throw timeout error.
I have checked my internet inside emulator browser, the internet works fine.
I am confused why it doesn't work in my app.

I have done these:
cold load avd
put 8.8.4.4 into network setting
disable lan network
changed my list to http from https
turned off and on wifi
turned on and off airplane mode
turned on cellular data

any idea ?
thanks

Comment: Does your app use a proxy? Did you set 8.8.8.8 (Google's DNS) or 208.67.222.222 in your DNS configuration? Did you allow your app to use Internet in the app's Manifest?

Comment: No my app doesn't use proxy.
Yes I have set that DNS in my network configuration. (I have said that in my question)
Yes I have allowed my app to use internet (I have said that my app works fine before with Nox Player, but after installation of windows i didn't installed Nox Player, I want to use android AVD)

Comment: That seems to be a problem of the API you're calling. Just checkout if it happens with a physical device (if you have one), or just try to call the API from the browser.

Comment: Yes it woks with physical device, also works with laptop browser.